# Best way to initialize jquery plugin on DOM element in multiple templates

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I'm trying to use [chosen](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) on some form elements that are in various templates throughout a meteor app. For example:

**HTML**

```
<template name="personSettings">

  <!-- some code -->

  <template name="chosenSelect">
    <select class="chosen">
      <!-- options -->
    </select>
  </template>

  <!-- some code -->

</template>
```

**JS**

```
Template.chosenSelect.rendered = function() {
  $('.chosen').chosen()
}
```

Note that the JS at this point is irrelevant, because I get the **error**:

```
While building the application:
client/views/personSettings.html:27: Expected "template" end tag
...            </select>
```

I thought you could nest templates, so I'm not sure what the problem is. However, if it turns out I cannot nest templates, the question remains:

What is the best way to initiaize a jquery plugin on a DOM element (by class), that exists in multiple templates?

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed nest templates but your syntax is wrong :

HTML

```
<template name="chosenSelect">
  <select class="chosen">
    <!-- options -->
  </select>
</template>

<template name="personSettings">
  <!-- some code -->
  {{> chosenSelect}}
  <!-- some code -->
</template>
```

You must always declare templates within a single pair of matching `template` tags, if you need to call another template from within your template markup, use the template invokation / inclusion syntax `{{> myTemplate}}`.

JS

```
Template.chosenSelect.onRendered(function() {
  this.$(".chosen").chosen()
});
```

When it comes to initializng jQuery plugins within template instances, use the `onRendered` lifecycle event and prefer using scoped jQuery object (`this.$`).

Comment: Ah, for some reason I associated doing `{{> chosenSelect}}` with having to put the select in a separate HTML partial. But this makes sense. However - what if I make multiple templates with the name chosenSelect? Will it know to pull in the template residing on the same page? I think I end up with the same problem

Comment: Template names need to be unique, but you can include the same template as many times from as many templates as you want. What exactly are you trying to do?